# css 'clip-path' doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm creating an avatar underlay using clip-path, and border radius, to show a background colour. Firefox won't render the clipping path, even when the vendor prefix is used.

Any help appreciated.

The html:

```
<div class="avatar-wrapper">
<div class="circle-underlay">&nbsp;</div>
<img class="avatar-img" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6caf8757aa60bda77594e8d8fdd819d9?s=38" width="38" height="38" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.avatar-wrapper{
position: relative;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
}

.circle-underlay {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 48px;
height: 48px; 
background:#cc3300;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.avatar-img{
position: absolute;
top:5px;
left: 5px;
-moz-clip-path: circle(50%,50%,50%);
-webkit-clip-path: circle(50%,50%,50%);
clip-path: circle(50%,50%,50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LyDHP/

Comment: Whats the question? Your just stating something. Much better now you edited.

Comment: @Ruddy The page published before I was finished editing. I have big hands.

Comment: As far as I know, FireFox does not support `clip-path`. I just had another look around and cant find a lot on it.

Comment: You can achieve the same with less html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/LyDHP/1/

Comment: @Pete Thanks for this workaround, works perfectly. I can't make it the correct answer as it's in a comment though!

Comment: @dmc, you're welcome!  Answer added - also realised you don't need the absolute positioning of the image

Comment: @Pete Appreciated! I'd gone and gotten tunnel vision on using clip-path and masks. This is far more graceful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the following HTML:

```
<div class="avatar-wrapper">
    <img class="avatar-img" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6caf8757aa60bda77594e8d8fdd819d9?s=38" width="38" height="38" />
</div>
```

and css:

```
.avatar-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border:5px solid #cc3300;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[You can achieve the required result](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/LyDHP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Good news, the basic support of "clip-path" without svg will be added to Firefox 54, it's still in beta for now but the public released is planed for June 14.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/54

> - clip-path now supports basic shapes (bug 1247229).