# Clip-path doesn't work in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, svg, clip-path

I have a `nav` element that on mouse hover reveal my menu, it works fine on Safari and Chrome however not in Firefox nor in IE:

```css
/* start nav menu morph */

nav {
  width: 23%;
  background: #222222;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(16px at 30px 24px);
  clip-path: circle(16px at 30px 24px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-clip-path 0.5625s, clip-path 0.375s;
  transition: -webkit-clip-path 0.5625s, clip-path 0.375s;
}
nav:hover {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.75s;
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(500px at 225px 24px);
  clip-path: circle(500px at 225px 24px);
}
nav a {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #ffe082;
}
nav a:active {
  background: #ffca28;
}
.nav-sim {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -6px;
}
.navicon {
  padding: 23px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 32px 24px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 32px 24px;
  transform-origin: 32px 24px;
}
.navicon div {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(254, 70, 70);
}
.navicon div:before,
.navicon div:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(254, 70, 70);
  position: absolute;
}
.navicon div:before {
  top: -7px;
}
.navicon div:after {
  top: 7px;
}
.fa-sim {
  font-size: large;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
/* end nav menu morph */
```

```html
<noscript>
  <style>
    #navmenusim {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</noscript>
<nav class="nav-sim" id="navmenusim">
  <div class="navicon">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="" rel="">Home<i class="fa fa-home icon i-sim fa-sim"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="" rel="">Blog<i class="fa fa-rss icon i-sim fa-sim"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="" rel="">Contact<i class="fa fa-mail icon i-sim fa-sim"></i></a> 
</nav>
```

The menu in Firefox and IE is always visible, the clip-path doesn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: CSS `clip-path` won't work in FF. You need to use SVG and `url()` syntax for FF support. IE won't support any version of `clip-path`. You can check browser compatibility at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Comment: @Harry Thanks, how can I hide this `nav` for both browsers?

Comment: I tried something like `<script>
 var FIREFOX = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if (FIREFOX) {
  document.getElementById("navmenusim").style.display="none";
}
</script>` but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers on this already e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816793/clip-path-doesnt-work-in-firefox-values do none of them help you?

Comment: @Simone: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/j7Lw4m54/) fiddle uses a totally different approach with properties all of which are supported on IE and FF. If you wish to go down this route, I'll help you tune it further.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for this great solution, however is there any chance to have a circle expansion instead of square onhover?

Comment: @Simone: Unless we use an extra element and some complex stuff, the best that can be achieved is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/j7Lw4m54/2/). It kind of goes from a circle to an oval and finally turns into a square.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not very familiar with `clip-path` but I read some of those solutions and tried from console without any good results

Comment: @Harry Yes it's better without `border-radius`. Is there a way to display this solution only for browsers FF and IE ( I would like to keep my version for Chrome and Safari)

Comment: @Simone: Maybe possible with JS but I wouldn't really recommend doing it. It is better to keep it consistent (more of a personal choice though). By the way, would you mind if I add that as an answer?

Comment: @Harry of course,I wanted to suggest before, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to the question, CSS `clip-path` won't work in Firefox. You would need to use SVG along with `url()` syntax for Firefox support. IE (even 11 and Edge) supports neither the CSS or SVG version of `clip-path`. You can check browser compatibility chart at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

You can make use of the `max-width`, `max-height`, `border-radius` and `overflow` properties to sort of get a similar output to what you need. Below is a sample snippet which should work in all browsers.

```css
/* start nav menu morph */

nav {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 23%;
  background: #222222;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .375s, max-width .375s, border-radius .125s .25s;
}
nav:hover {
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  transition: max-height .75s ease-out, max-width .75s ease-out, border-radius .75s ease-out;
}
nav a {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #ffe082;
}
nav a:active {
  background: #ffca28;
}
.nav-sim {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -6px;
}
.navicon {
  padding: 23px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 32px 24px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 32px 24px;
  transform-origin: 32px 24px;
}
.navicon div {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(254, 70, 70);
}
.navicon div:before,
.navicon div:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(254, 70, 70);
  position: absolute;
}
.navicon div:before {
  top: -7px;
}
.navicon div:after {
  top: 7px;
}
.fa-sim {
  font-size: large;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
/* end nav menu morph */
```

```html
<nav class="nav-sim" id="navmenusim">
  <div class="navicon">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="" rel="">Home<i class="fa fa-home icon i-sim fa-sim"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="" rel="">Blog<i class="fa fa-rss icon i-sim fa-sim"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="" rel="">Contact<i class="fa fa-mail icon i-sim fa-sim"></i></a> 
</nav>
```