# Crop image using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to crop 50px from the top of an image. I am following the below reference but for some reason it didn't work in FF but worked in Chrome.

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Html:

```
<img src="https://s30.postimg.org/lkqxmrk29/about.jpg" class="rectshape">
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/a4j343hg/1/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: fiddle is working!! Whats the question?

Comment: This works good for me! Maybe you are using browser that not support clip property?

Comment: It looks working on jsfiddle.

Comment: OP probably wants to not see the top 50px

Comment: @mariobros Ahh yes it works in Chrome but not in FF

Comment: are you using Firefox ?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: have you tried using `-moz-clip-path`?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816793/clip-path-doesnt-work-in-firefox-values

Comment: @mrid Yes I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the clip path is [not supported very well](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), why not use `overflow: hidden` and a container element? Here is your [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4j343hg/3/) demonstrating this. A negative margin can be used to hide part of the image. Cropping the image from other sides can be accomplished easily by using negative margin on the other sides. Only if you want a non-rectangular clipping path, you will have to resort to the SVG [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) that was referred to in the comments. [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qoLypy8/).

```css
.rectshape {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.rectshape > img {
  margin-top: -50px;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectshape">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
</div>
<div class="rectshape">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
</div>
<div class="rectshape">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this concept.. Actually I have few images stacked one below another so it's bit difficult to use negative margin.

Comment: The negative margin is only applied to the image, it does not extend to the container. I will update my answer to include stacked images.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot for your help.